# Flutter App- Firebase Core Build 2.7.0 Error

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, android-studio

**I installed the firebase plugins that I needed to install in my project that I developed with Flutter in Android Studio, but it gives an error while getting the firebase_core build and does not start.**

I install flutter extension but get error

[Error Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vskMl.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxDR0.png)

[Error Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHNka.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.